# Does Firebase synchronise logged events when app is closed?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

What happens with [logged events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events) if there is no internet connection while the app is running and app is never opened after that?

Does Firebase use some kind of [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) (and other alternative for iOS) to synchronised logged events when the the internet connection appears?

Comment: Don't know about Android implementation, but on iOS usual application can't do background tasks long time after it was closed so I expect that if the app is never opened again - iOS events are lost forever

Comment: @SergGr that is indeed the behavior of Firebase Analytics on iOS. Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I'd prefer to wait for somebody who knows how it works on Android because I don't and can't deduct from general knowledge as for iOS. I think that given SO limitations of single accepted answer, it is better to have single response for both platforms

Comment: @SergGr  what about background execution (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html). Could the data be sent using "Fetching Small Amounts of Content Opportunistically" or "Tracking the User’s Location"?

Comment: As for `Executing Finite-Length Tasks` to quote the spec you referenced "If your app is in the middle of a task and needs **a little** extra time to complete that task". From my experience on real hardware (unlike simulators), your "extra time" is limitted to about 5 minutes which is probably not enough for your "device is offline" case. As for `Implementing Long-Running Tasks`, it can't be done by an "usual" application as it requires special metadata flags and Apple checks them before approval for AppStore so Firebase can't rely on them (and you probably will not get them anyway).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the comments on the question, @SergGr and @Frank indicate that on iOS, the event are never uploaded.

On Android, my observations are that the events are logged to a shared system service (not part of the app) which handles the buffering and uploading. Thus, events logged when there is no internet connection are later uploaded by the service, regardless of whether the originating app is still running or not.

This behavior can be observed by [enabling analytics logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events#view_events_in_the_android_studio_debug_log) and viewing the log output in an `adb` window.  The tag for the system service is FA-SVC.

Some examples of excerpted log output are included below.  I performed these steps for my test:

1. Turned on Airplane Mode
2. Ran app to generate events
3. Put app in background, swiped from recent tasks list to kill it
4. Disabled Airplane Mode
5. Waited for FA-SVC to run and upload events (this might be as long as an hour)
6. Examined buffer of the uploaded event data logged by FA-SVC to confirm that app events were included

---

```
// uploading seems occur about every hour
03-02 07:40:42.397 V/FA-SVC  ( 1889): Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 3599957
// the service detects connectivity changes
03-02 06:47:16.496 V/FA-SVC  ( 1889): NetworkBroadcastReceiver received action: android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
// this log marks the start of upload; followed by logs for each uploaded event
03-02 07:40:41.757 V/FA-SVC  ( 1889): Uploading data. app, uncompressed size, data: com.qbix.xxxx, 3450
```